# Binding React-Admin ReferenceInput with SelectInput to render on DOM

Tags: react-admin

I have two endpoints

> api/instruction
>   api/subject

from my server, model Instructions has a reference field called subject.

On my react-admin frontend, I'd like to CREATE(CRUD) a new Instruction instance.

Following [this tutorial](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#referenceinput) I have implemented my InstructionCreate as below

```
export const InstructionCreate = (props) => (
    <Create  title="New Instruction"{...props}>
        <SimpleForm>
             <ReferenceInput label="Subject" source="subject" reference="subject/">
                <SelectInput optionText="name" />
            </ReferenceInput>   
        </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
```

> When I render my Create component, from chrome console, under networktab, I can see a list of subject objects returned.
>
> The list has two objects(pulled from server) and the objects have a property 'name'

However, i get a console  error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
>
> The above error occurred in the

In case one needs my app.js, from which I can successfully CRUD the api/subject endpoint

```
const App = () => (    
     <Admin 
         dataProvider={dataProvider}  

         <Resource name="subject" title="Subjects" list={SubjectList} create={SubjectCreate} edit={SubjectEdit}  icon={GroupIcon}/>
         <Resource name="instruction" title="Instructions" list={InstructionList} edit={InstructionEdit} create={InstructionCreate} icon={InstructionIcon}/>

     </Admin>
     );
```

> GET api/subject - returns a list of dictionaries

[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Subject 2"
        },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Subject 1"
    }
]

Comment: Which data provider are you using? It looks like it does not correctly return its data

Comment: @GildasGarcia

Hello again mate?

This is what am using.
>ra-data-simple-rest

Please clarify what you mean by your response, that it does not return its data

Comment: Can you post an extract of your API response for this specific query? It might be because it is not in the format expected by the `ra-data-simple-rest` provider

Comment: @GildasGarcia

Ive added the response

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this. 
The error was on my side for including a trailing '/' on the reference var

> Changed this line

```
<ReferenceInput label="Subject" source="subject" reference="subject/">
```

> to

```
<ReferenceInput label="Subject" source="subject" reference="subject">
```